# Get Value from Params in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, parameters, react-hooks

I'm trying to get just the "approved" word there. The "approved" word there is dynamic. How can i get it? What will be the ideal way to do this on React? Check this code below

**Code**

```
const location = useLocation();
console.log(location);
```

**output of the console.log:**

```
{ "pathname": "/orders/approved/1", "search": "", "hash": "", "key": "rzbem0" }
```

Comment: will it always be in that position?

Comment: @RedBaron. Yesssss

Comment: check answer Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's the same position all the time then use this:

`"/orders/approved/1".split('/')[2]` will return `approved` in this case

`"/orders/somethingElse/1".split('/')[2]` will return `somethingElse` in this case